# Mayavi Python How to dye each 3D vertex differently

Tags: python, mayavi, ply, mayavi.mlab

I wrote a script that loads a 3D point cloud in ply format converts it to an np array and then draws the point cloud with mayavi. This process works 
[image: 3D Recon of the ET example]

But the color of the vertices is not taken into account. There is a function that dye all points the same but I would like to use the colors for each point from the ply file like in meshlab. Thanks in advance best Max

Comment: Could you please provide the XYZ coordinates for these points at https://pastebin.com/ to test loading them? Which coordinate X, Y or Z is the vertical? (As I can see - it is a figure, so, after testing it will be obvious).